# How can copper(II) sulfate crystallize outside a glass vial?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, intermolecular-forces

I'm making copper sulfate crystals in glasses. Within a few weeks, the copper sulfate seems to crystallize both inside and outside the glass:

(A few weeks after making a new solution)
[image]
(Yet another few weeks later)
[image]

How is that possible? The glasses haven't moved for all those weeks. Is that pure capillary action, or is there another phenomenon?

Comment: Indeed, capillary effect is enough. New portions of solution get higher and higher up, and deposit crystals to build more capillaries, much like a horde of guys with ladders storming some medieval fortress.